# EF and dynamic table names

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic, mapping

I am checking if there is way to dynamically change the table mapped to an Entity in EF 6. The schema of the table doesn't change, just the name. For example, I have an Entity called Orders, then I need to assign this Entity to a SQL view dynamically created when the program runs. The name of the view is generated in run-time, so I need to map that view name to the Orders entity in run-time. Any idea how to do this?
Thanks in advance.
-Fernando

Answer (score 2):

So long as the table name doesn't change while your program is running, you can just map in in OnModelCreating.  Eg

```
   class Db: DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClassRoom> Classrooms { get; set; }

        public DbSet<StudentToClassRoom> StudentToClassRoom { get; set; }

        private string GetStudentTableName()
        {
            return "Student123";
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable(GetStudentTableName());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }
```

Comment: But the model is created before the view is created, I will add this to the question, thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I will take a look at this because I am thinking we can set the view name when app starts. Will check and let you know, thanks.